# How to return File[] array after adding all files to it

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to this group. Please suggest how to return `File[]` array as my code below is giving `NullPointerException` when I am trying to add all text files from "D:\" to `File[]` array, as I want to return all text files as an `File[]` array which will be used in another method to read all text files.

```
File[] allFiles;

int i = 0;

public File[] findFiles(File source) {

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!pathname.isHidden()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    File[] list = source.listFiles(filter);
    if (list != null) {
        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(f);
            }
            if (f.getName().contains("txt")) {
                System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

                allFiles[i] = f; // it is giving nullpointerexception
                i++;
            }

        }
    }

    return allFiles; // want to return this to another method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're having is you've not initialized `allFiles` before using it...

```
File[] list = source.listFiles(filter);
if (list != null) {
    for (File f : list) {
            //...
            // still null
            allFiles[i] = f; // it is giving nullpointerexception
```

You could use `allFiles = new File[list.length]`, but the problem here is you could end up with `null` elements in the list, as you are filtering out elements...

Instead, you could use your `FileFilter`, that's what it's there for...for example...

```
public File[] findFiles(File source) {

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {

            return !pathname.isHidden() && 
                   pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");

        }
    };

    File[] list = source.listFiles(filter);

    return list;
}
```

Basically, what this does is checks to see if the file is not hidden and if its name ends with `.txt`, as an example...

**Updated**

Because you're doing a recursive look up, you really need some way to add new files to your array and grow it dynamically.

While you can do this with plain old arrays, some kind of `List` would be much easier, for example...

The following uses the `FileFilter` to find all non-hidden files that directories or end in `.txt`

It then sorts the resulting list of files, so that the "files" appear first and the "directories" or sorted to the bottom, this is a nit pick, but ensure a certain order of files in the list.

It then processes the file list, adding the "files" to the `List` and recurisivly scanning the "directories", adding the results to the `List`...

```
public static File[] findFiles(File source) {

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return !pathname.isHidden() && 
                    (pathname.isDirectory() || 
                    pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"));
        }
    };

    File[] files = source.listFiles(filter);
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            int compare = 0;
            if (o1.isDirectory() && o2.isDirectory()) {
                compare = 0;
            } else if (o1.isFile()) {
                compare = -1;
            } else {
                compare = 1;
            }
            return compare;
        }
    });

    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(25);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(file);
        } else {
            fileList.addAll(Arrays.asList(findFiles(file)));
        }
    }

    return fileList.toArray(new File[fileList.size()]);
}
```

As an example...

Comment: Thanks alot:) why I dint notice that :(

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just initialize the `allFiles` array

```
File[] list = source.listFiles(filter);

// initialize here because we know the size now.
allFiles = new File[list.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `File[] allFiles`,Like -

```
File[] allFiles = new File[list.length];
```

Alternatively you can use `List` instead of `Array`, which is dynamic array(not fixed size).

Initialization -

```
List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
```

Adding element -

```
allFiles.add(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
@Override
public boolean accept(File pathname) {
  return !pathname.isHidden() &&  
         pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
};

File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.print("is a directory");
    } else {
        System.out.print("is a file");
    }
    System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
}
```